# ACPI Error after kernel update with Fedora 25

Tags: linux, fedora, kernel

I started having some issues after the latest kernel update (4.9.5-200). I'm running Fedora 25 on a ThinkPad T530.

When I boot with the latest kernel, I get the following error message on the screen (see attached image).

[acpi error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeP4H.png)

Fedora continues to boot with the graphical interface (Fedora Logo booting) and before the boot process continues to the login screen, the error message appears again and remains stuck. I don't get the graphical login screen.

Has anyone an idea why this is happening and how to fix it? Has it something to do with the graphics drivers? What changed suddenly in the new kernel?

I appreciate any help or information!

Comment: Have you posted this on the fedora forums? I'm sure you will get better responses over there - http://fedoraforum.org/

Comment: I did, but haven't received any response yet. I don't know if anyone else has the same issue on a ThinkPad.

Comment: Any possibility of downgrading until you find out some more info about it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing right now, running the latest stable kernel. Also, hoping with any new kernel update that this issue might be resolved. Otherwise, I have no idea what else to do and how to really solve it.

Comment: Sorry I can't help, I'm sure someone who uses Linux will see this and help you out. The Kernel may not be Fedora specific, so as you are searching for answers - consider expanding your search to other Linux disto's using the same kernel.

Comment: Good point. I should do that.